# Change Google Sheets displaying "0" for =Sum formulas

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm putting together a spreadsheet in Google Sheets to keep track of my nutrition and weight loss.

I want to make 2 charts, 1 that will display my weight over time and one that will display my calorie changes so I can compare the two. I have an issue with the calorie chart. On my tracker sheet I have columns I enter my protein fat and carb amounts and then the total calories get calculated using the formula below and entered in a separate cell.

```
=SUM(K12 * 4)+(L12 * 9)+(M12 * 4)
```

My problem is, these cells will always display a zero which messes up the look of the chart. I was wondering if there was a way I could use the `SUM` formula above or a different formula that would not automatically display a zero.

Comment: A fairly simple array formula would accomplish this. However, I'd need to see the sheet to know the range and parameters. If you'd like, share a link to your sheet (or to a copy of it), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" when you create it.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula instead

```
=IF(K12="","",SUM(K12 * 4)+(L12 * 9)+(M12 * 4))
```

This formula says:
If cell `K12` is empty, show empty. If not, show the result of `SUM(K12 * 4)+(L12 * 9)+(M12 * 4))`

Comment: Thanks so much, that works perfectly :)

Comment: Glad I could help.